# How to read html entities using json response in Symfony2

Tags: json, symfony

I need to display below html entities content  `"<JHJ?fg:<?"` 
I retrive data from database and pass this content through jsonresponse. But It displayed only like `"<JHJ?fg:` Not display full content `"<JHJ?fg:<?"`.

```
$elementsJson = "<JHJ?fg:<?";
return new JsonResponse(array('data' => $elementsJson));
```

Pls anyone help me.

Comment: What MIME receives your browser? (in developer tools)

Comment: header('Content-Type: application/json'); I used above code. but not display. I am using netbeans

Comment: On Symfony 2.8 I have this content: ``{"data":"\u003CJHJ?fg:\u003C?"}``. Need some information on your environment.